# android - Radio Buttons in a Fragment causing crash

Tags: android, android-fragments, radio-button, radio-group, oncheckedchanged

This crashes when the fragment has launched. Could it be in the radio-button code?

```
    RadioGroup q1;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        q1 = (RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioGQ1);
        q1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exercise, container, false);

    }
    rest -> http://pastebin.com/cRptSmD4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inflate the views first.

```
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exercise, container, false);
q1 = (RadioGroup) root.findViewById(R.id.radioGQ1);
q1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
return root;
```

`getView()` returns null until you have returned a view hierarchy from `onCreateView()`, so you should not be calling `getView()` inside that method.

Answer (score 0):

The `Context` of `Fragment` is `getActivity`, if you are not initializing any view, use `getActivity()`. So in your code:

Replace this:

```
q1 = (RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioGQ1);
```

With this code:

```
q1 = (RadioGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.radioGQ1);
```